# Cannot access USB-connected android phone when system language is greek

Tags: usb, android, language-support, internationalization

I have a problem when connecting my android phone through a USB.
My system language is Greek (Modern).
In particular, when I connect the phone, the following window appears:

[image: On connection to USB]

This would normally be ok, but I can't really do anything with the phone icon that appears. When double clicking, what I get is an error:

[image: Android device error]

I'm guessing that the '/' characters on the (automatically generated in greek) name of the phone device are the source of the problem. The (greek) name of the device is:

`Εσωτ/κή αποθ/ση`

which is meant as an abbreviation of the full wording, which would be:

`Εσωτερική αποθήκευση`

meaning ''internal storage''. This saves a few characters on the device name but causes more problems though :)

Any thoughts about getting around this problem? Is there probably some way of forcing a different name on the device? I guess that re-installing with English as system language is a solution, but I'd obviously like to avoid that.

Comment: Is the device name auto generated, or you named it? Because in Linux any "/" denotes path. Is it possible to rename the device with "-" or "_"?

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee The device name is auto generated, and I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Can't you rename the phone in your phone's settings? If yes, please don't put space between two words. You may use "-" or "_" to separate two words though.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee The name that contains the slashes is *not* the name of the phone. Like I say in the question, it is an abbreviation of the phrase "internal storage" in greek.

Comment: Okay, what is the output of 'sudo fdisk -l' (phone attached state)? What is the name showing in gparted?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive : Might be of your interest

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee Thanks, but neither fdisk nor gparted does any good. My phone doesn't show up in any of these.

Comment: Highly unlikely, are all the USB ports and the Data cable in good shape?

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee I can connect using the same cable and phone under Windows on the same machine, so yes.

Comment: One final thought as far my understanding goes, are all MTP packages like mtpfs, jmtpfs etc. installed?